# R - tmap_animation generates gif with green frames

Tags: r, animation, tmap

I'm trying to create an animated GIF using tmap and display it in my Shiny app. When I use tm_shape() + tm_polygons() for a single date, the image produced is always OK. However, when I use tm_facets() and feed the result to tmap_animation, the resulting GIF has random dark green frames, as per the below.[image]

Here is the code I am using the generate the animation:

```
data(World)

confirmed = read.csv('./data/time_series_covid_19_confirmed.csv', stringsAsFactors = T) %>%
  select(-Province.State, -Country.Region) %>%
  pivot_longer(!c('Lat', 'Long', 'iso3'), names_to = 'date', values_to = 'confirmed') %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(gsub('X', '', date), '%m.%d.%Y')) %>%
  group_by(iso3, date) %>%
  summarise(confirmed = sum(confirmed)) %>%
  mutate(perc_change = 100 * ifelse(
      lag(confirmed, default = 0) == 0 | confirmed < 1000 | lag(confirmed) > confirmed, 
      0, 
      (confirmed - lag(confirmed)) / lag(confirmed)
    )
  ) %>%
  inner_join(select(World, iso_a3, geometry), by=c('iso3' = 'iso_a3')) %>%
  st_sf()

conf_anim = confirmed %>%
  filter(date < '2020-02-28') %>%
  tm_shape() + tm_polygons('perc_change', style='cont') +
  # tm_fill('perc_change', palette='Blues', style='fixed', 
  #         breaks=c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, Inf)) + tm_borders() +
  tm_facets(along='date', free.coords = F)

tmap_animation(conf_anim, filename = './www/conf_anim.gif', delay=50)
```

Anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is struggling with this, I was able to create a workaround using tmap, gifski (which tmap uses to generate GIFs), dplyr, and the png library. **This method is NOT fast and generating a GIF this way may take a long time.** Another answer mentioned using an MP4 format instead of GIF - this method is far faster if that is an option for you.

Assuming you have an sf object named *df_sf* which you are trying to facet along *facet_along_col_str* and the first argument to tm_polygons is *polygon_col_str*, here is code that will help you generate a GIF:

```
library(tmap)
library(gifski)
library(png)
library(dplyr)

generate_gif = function(sf_df, facet_along_col_str, polygon_col_str, gif_file, delay) {
  dims = get_dims(sf_df, facet_along_col_str, polygon_col_str)
  save_gif(get_maps(sf_df), height=dims[1], width=dims[2], delay=delay, gif_file=gif_file)
}

get_dims = function(sf_df, facet_along, polygon_col) {
  slice = st_drop_geometry(select(sf_df, !!as.symbol(map_slice_col)))[[1]][1]
  t = tm_shape(filter(sf_df, !!as.symbol(map_slice_col) == slice)) +
    tm_polygons(polygons_col)
  filename = tempfile(fileext='.png')
  tmap_save(t, filename=filename)
  dims = dim(readPNG(filename))
  file.remove(filename)

  return(dims)
}

get_maps = function(sf_df, facet_along, polygon_col) {
  slices = st_drop_geometry(select(sf_df, !!as.symbol(map_slice_col)))[[1]]
  slices = sort(unique(slices))
  for (i in 1:length(slices)) {
    t = tm_shape(filter(sf_df, !!as.symbol(facet_along) == slices[i])) +
      tm_polygons(polygon_col)
    print(t)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. [I asked about it](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/553) on the `tmap` GitHub issues tab and the team traced it to an issue with the `gifski` package `tmap` uses to generate gif animations. I found the same thing was happening for animations made with `gifski` without using `tmap`.

The workaround mtennekes suggested for now was to save the animation as an mp4 rather than gif, which uses the `av` package:

```
tmap_animation(conf_anim, filename = './www/conf_anim.mp4', delay=50)
```

Not a full fix, but hope it helps for your immediate application.

Comment: +1 for a faster method. I posted an answer below that allows you to generate a gif using gifski and tmap which I have marked as the correct answer, as the original question was how to generate a gif and because I'm shameless XD

Comment: FYI i'm not convinced that the issue is with gifski - setting the width and height in gifski::save_gif to the values of a png generated by tmap_save solved the issue. Maybe this has something to do with resizing?

Comment: @Jay Interesting. I ran the example code for the gifski package (generating a ggplot animation using gapminder data) and it also contained green frames, so to me that suggests that at least the problem is not in tmap. Glad you worked out a solution for generating a GIF!